# Hiding State Changes of Org Mode Repeating Task

Tags: org-mode

I have several repeating tasks (some with the "habit" style). I like my setup but now I have a lot state changes log just below the not drawers. For example:

```
** TODO Random Task                                                   :dailies:
SCHEDULED: <2015-12-03 Thu 13:00 ++1d>
:PROPERTIES:
:LAST_REPEAT: [2015-12-02 Wed 16:59]
:ID:       BA24BAA8-5094-49C9-A014-619C8D98F25E
:STYLE:    habit
:RESET_CHECK_BOXES: t
:CATEGORY: AccordionLearn
:END:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2015-12-02 Wed 16:59]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2015-12-01 Tue 14:16]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2015-11-27 Fri 18:55]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2015-11-23 Mon 22:02]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2015-11-18 Wed 17:02]
```

is there a way to hide the  Lines:  `- State "DONE"       from "TODO"    ...`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can customize `org-log-into-drawer` to `t` rather than `nil`.

This way, all state changes and notes will be stored into a drawer called `LOGBOOK`.

You can give another name to this drawer if you wish, or you can make this customization for a file only (adding a  `#+STARTUP: logdrawer` directive), or inside a heading (by setting the `LOG_INTO_DRAWER` property).

Answer (score 0):

Change the `org-log-repeat` variable to `nil`.

```
(setq org-log-repeat nil)
```

See manual, [section 8.3.2](https://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html#FOOT75) note 75.